# iOS How to reduce PDF size before uploading?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am uploading PDFs from Dropbox/iCloud. But file sizes are like 50MB, 100MB. As of app requirement, there is no limit for file size to upload. How to reduce the file size before uploading to server?

Comment: if file type is not a problem, you can convert PDFs into low quality image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [libHaru library](https://github.com/akisute/iPhonePDF) to generate any kind of pdf. Try to reduce your pdf size while creating the pdf itself.